# как работает strtotime

Tags: php

`strtotime('2018-09-20 16:49:54')` кидаю первый аргумент. Эта функция чутко реагирует на настройки сервера временной зоны. Читал мануал - не понял. Дата которую мы кинули воспринимается сервером как дата нулевого меридиана и к ней прибавляется местное время настроенное на сервере или дата воспринимается как местное время и отнимается это местное время чтобы получить время нулевого меридиана?

В ответе на одном сервере 1537487394
На другом 1537451394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *дата воспринимается как местное время*

Да, именно так.

Результат работы функции `strtotime()` зависит от часового пояса, установленного в конфигурации PHP (директива `date.timezone`). К примеру, если у вас стоит часовой пояс `Europe/London`, то летом это будет `UTC+01:00`. PHP определяет, что дата передана в этом часовом поясе и чтобы привести её к `UTC` нужно вычесть 1 час. В итоге мы получаем unixtime равный **1537458594**.

Если конвертировать эту метку времени в обычную дату в любом онлайн конвертере, то мы получим "2018-09-20 **15**:49:54", то есть на 1 час меньше того, что мы передавали в аргументе `strtotime()`. А если вы вызовете на локальном сервере функцию `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` и подставите во второй аргумент полученный unixtime, то получите уже дату с учётом вашего локального часового пояса: "2018-09-20 **16**:49:54".

Также предположу, что на серверах установлены следующие часовые пояса:

- 1537487394 — `UTC-07:00`,
- 1537451394 — `UTC+03:00`.